# How to hide the horizontal border after tabs in a GTKNotebook?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gtk, gtk2

I am completely new to the Gtk framework. We have a legacy product built using Gtk+ 2/C++. Here's what I'm trying to do: We have GtkNotebook widgets with several tabs. At times, there is only a single tab visible. In such cases, the appearance of the notebook needs to be changed in such a way that it doesn't look like a tabbed control. As a first step, I have changed the colour of the background so it more or less looks seamless. But there's this border (highlighted in the screenshot attached) which I can't seem to get rid of or hide. I have tried `gtk_notebook_set_tab_hborder`, `gtk_notebook_set_tab_vborder`, `gtk_container_set_border_width` but to no avail. I have also tried the following in a gtkrc file without success.

- `GtkNotebook::tab-border = 0`
- `GtkNotebook::tab-hborder = 0`
- `GtkNotebook::tab-vborder = 0`
- `GtkNotebook::show-border = 0`

So the obvious question is that is it possible to hide it at all? If so, how? :)

I would highly appreciate it if someone could lead me in the right direction.

Reference: https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/index.html
[image]

Comment: The whole point of using `GtkNotebook` is because it has tabs. If you're going to remove the tabs, but still need to switch between pages easily, why don't you use the `GtkStack` widget instead? It has pages that can easily be switched back and forth, and it doesn't have tabs.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Thank you for your suggestions. As I mentioned, it is a legacy product built on an older version of Gtk (GTK+ 2) and I don't think GtkStack is available in this version. Nevertheless, the appearance of the GtkStack is not consistent with what we already have.